# How to assign lead to campaigns in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have about 10 leads and 10 campaigns , now how to assign leads to campaigns in CRM 2011 and to generate report..

How to do this assignment .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want, but one thing you can do is you have Marketing List which you can add Leads, Contacts or Accounts. A new feature is Dynamics Marketing List that is updated if a criteria from a entity changed. If i don't answer nothing about your question put more details please.

Take a look in some tutorials:

- https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmsoftwareblog/archive/2012/11/13/simplifying-campaigns-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkjZYhUZDbc

Comment: Actually i am new to CRM , ok i have added leads or contacts to marketing lists after that , how to associate this with Campaigns?